# R: Correlation Loop for dataset

Tags: r

This is my first question here, but i'm a little bit desperated and i would really appreciate some ideas.

My dataset looks like this (a small sample):
[Mydata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpLNu.png)

with every row representing one person.

Now my goal is to calculate the mean intercorrelation between "hubs" for each person (N = 1363 - that's part of the problem).

Each "hub" would consist of three items seen in the image, e.g. BDI10,BDI11,BDI12.
Next step is to compute the correlations between these - let's say 8 "hubs" - per person to get the mean intercorrelations between these "hubs" per person.

That's quite a lot of data rearrangement to do if i calcutate this per person.

So my question here is: Has anyone here an idea about a "loop" so i don't have to go through this process 1363 times to create my variable? :)

Thank you so much in advance!

Phil

Edit:
Hey, thanks for the answer!
I adjusted your code in a way that i want to calculate the mean correlation between mood, guilt and concentration for each person. Mood, guilt and concentration are represented by three items each.

```
df <- data.frame(replicate(9,sample(0:2,5,rep=TRUE)))
library(plyr)
rename(df, c("X1"="Mood1", "X2"="Mood2","X3"="Mood3", "X4"="Guilt1","X5"="Guilt2", "X6"="Guilt3","X7"="Concentration1", "X8"="Concentration2", "X9"="Concentration3"))
df$ID <- seq.int(nrow(df))
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Sotos is right in that it will be much easier to assist you if you provide some minimum set of data (that we easily can copy/paste/run in our own R sessions) and then state your question in terms of that minimal example.  For example, could you adapt the following to give people who want to help you something to work with?  `df <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:2,5,rep=TRUE)))`   I.e. add different column names (to represent your hubs) if you need to and if it's applicable add a column for person_id.